# bitset not working with some numbers

Tags: c++, bitset

i am trying to convert 8 Byte wide number to bit strings .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
     void getAsString(int64_t mask )
    {
        printf("mask = %lld\n", mask);
        std::string test = std::bitset< 64 >( mask ).to_string();
        printf("test = %s \n", test.c_str() );
    }

    int main()
    {
        int64_t allowedBits[4] = { 0x0000000000000001L, 0x0000000000010000L, 0x0000000100000000L, 0x0001000000000000L };
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            getAsString(allowedBits[i]);
        }
    }
```

Below is the output on Linux Machine

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

```
mask = 1
test = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 
mask = 65536
test = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000 
mask = 4294967296
test = 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000 
mask = 281474976710656
test = 0000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Same code this machine .
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
Release:    6.8
Codename:   Final

g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)

Give the below output

```
mask = 1
test = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
mask = 65536
test = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000
mask = 4294967296
test = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mask = 281474976710656
test = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I have checked the width of the int64_t . it is 8 in both machines. 
For mask 4294967296 and 281474976710656 the string is zero .

Any help here would be really appreciated .

Comment: If `int64_t` isn't 8 bytes you've got problems.

Comment: What is the type of `mask`?  Hint: that means provide a [mcve]

Comment: You've got something funky going on because [it works for me](http://codepad.org/oPN4kP2X).

Comment: mask is of type int64_t. I have checked the width on my machine ,the size is shown as 8 .
printf("size = %d", sizeof(int64_t));
size = 8, @NathanOliver Sorry for not posting it correctly , its 1 am in the morning here and i am stcuk with this .

Comment: How do you set `mask`?  Do you use something like `mask = 4294967296`?

Comment: Work as expected [here](https://ideone.com/vALKub).

Comment: Most likely missing long/long long suffixes for integer literals as implicitly pointed by the others.

Comment: @tadman Even it works for me in my linux machine 
nik:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

With below compiler it seems to be not working .
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Any idea why ???

Comment: Do you compile with `-std=c++11` or eventually `-std=c++0x`? Constructor taking `unsigned long long` is available since C++11.

Comment: It's still not complete. (Complete should contain something like "`int main() {`" and "`}`".)

Comment: @NathanOliver Here the array where i have stored the number 
int64_t allowedBits[4] = { 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000010000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0001000000000000  } ;
This is the function i am using 
void getAsString(int64_t mask )
{
 printf("mask = %lld\n", mask);
 std::string test = std::bitset< 64 >( mask ).to_string();
 printf("test = %s \n", test.c_str() );
 combination.push_back( test );
}

Comment: @NiyazK Please edit that into the question.  It is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @NathanOliver Updated.

Comment: Please, as everyone's saying and as you keep ignoring, **make a complete, executable example** with all the necessary components. Also GCC 4.4.7 is from 2012. It's woefully out of date and that's a big problem. Is it a requirement that this code works on that platform? Update your server if that's an option. It's over-due for a rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the version of your compiler (gcc-4.4.7) the code is probably using a library which isn't updated to deal with C++11. The pre-C++11 specification of the `std::bitset<N>` constructor taking an integer used `unsigned long`. For a 32 bit build `unsigned long` uses 32 bits. As a result the argument will be truncated before passed to `std::bitset<N>`'s constructor.

I verified that `libstdc++` shipping with gcc-4.4.7 does use `unsigned long` as the type in the constructor.

Comment: I found the issue , it seems the makefile i was using for the build was having the flag -m32 .after changing it to -m64 it worked fine. Thank fof the help :)